# Alternate Background ListBox empty rows colors?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have made some research and I found a way to set an alternate background color for each `ListBoxItem`, but I want that background to continue even if the list box is empty.

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="288"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#D2D2D2"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,0,1,0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="27"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#333333"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#19000000"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Is it possible to set alternate background on the whole Height of a ListBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it is the item `Background` that enables this, so I would say that no, it is not possible. The only way that I could imagine that you could produce this effect would be to add empty items into the `ListBox`. However I would strongly advise that you not do that, as these empty items would still be selectable and this could confuse the users.

Comment: The only way I can think to do it - without creating a new control anyway - is to try something clever with making the background look like empty alternating items, but that's only possible if you know item height in advance, and making it match scroll positions is likely to be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late to the game here. I recently had to do exactly this for a project I was working on. Situations like this are best handled by not thinking too hard about it, and approaching the problem from the most basic angle. The simplest answer I've found is to have a border that has a tileable imagebrush background. It will automatically stretch to fill the treeview. Here is an example image:

[image]

And an image showing that the "empty" space also has the alternation colors.

[image]

I guess the actual trick here is how the Border is paired with the TreeView's ItemsPresenter. We have to put them both in a Grid. Look to the following style to see what I mean:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#363636" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both" />
                    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
                                <Border
                                    x:Name="Bd"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                    <ScrollViewer
                                        x:Name="_tv_scrollviewer_"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        Background="Transparent"
                                        CanContentScroll="false"
                                        Focusable="false"
                                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                        Style="{x:Null}"
                                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Border>
                                                <Border.Background>
                                                    <ImageBrush
                                                        ImageSource="/Voidwalker Engine Editor;component/Editor/Resources/Graphics/Editor/TreeView_Alternation.png"
                                                        TileMode="Tile"
                                                        Viewport="0,0,32,40"
                                                        ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
                                                </Border.Background>
                                            </Border>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
                                        <Setter TargetName="_tv_scrollviewer_" Property="CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
```

And an image showcasing the specific part of the style that's important:
[image]

Because the two controls are paired, they are both the same size, thus the tiling works automatically. Lastly, here is the actual image that's being used by the border (You may need a different size; I opted for each row to be 20 pixels high):

[image]

And that's it, ladies and gentlemen. Pretty sure that's the simplest and most elegant way to achieve it.

Answer (score -1):

I have done this before by creating two nearly identical controls and overlapping them. The bottom control has exactly the same layout properties and is bound to an arbitrarily large set of empty rows. The top version of the same box is bound to the actual data set. The difference is the top control's background is transparent so the set of empty rows shows through until the to box has filled up. This makes it so any sizing behavior affects everything in a predictable way.

I have some code-behind that causes the top box to be selected if the bottom one gets touched in any way.